# How to rename .docx blob file after getting response from server in Angular automatically without creating anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, blob, docx

I want to rename a blob file downloaded from a server. I looked for other solutions but they mainly deal with the created anchor link and setting name to anchor. I tried this approach:

```js
getRenamed(title): void {
    this.docTitle = title;
    this.requestService.download(title).subscribe((response) => {
      let thefile = new Blob([response], {
        type:
          "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
      });
      let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(thefile);
      window.open(url);
    });
  }
```

But the problem with this approach is that it creates a random filename. And I want to give it a specific filename.

Comment: why you don't want to use anchor element?

Comment: Internet explorer provides you navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);

Comment: or you can create url from backend instead of sending a blob in response. let backend be responsible for filename and file.

Comment: @AakashGarg Well, I am building client-side  for my clustering document system. The problem first it has to detect and then I have to ask them whether they want to download file or not in Dialog box. So, I think now using anchor with preset link is feasible I guess. But that might also work.

Comment: @AakashGarg that sounds better way.
thank you,

Comment: An vote would be appreciated.

Comment: I think since I am New Contributor, I don't have voting privileges. Sorry but help is highly appreciated.